# WP_Query breaks pagination

Tags: wp-query, customization, pagination

I've been on this problem for a week now. I've searched through countless posts that just aren't answering the question. It seems that my wp_query breaks pagination. I've looked through a lot of the post on wp_query and pagination on here but with still no joy.

As far as I can see it's set up correctly. I have one instance where it will show all posts in one page, and in the other it repeats the content on each page. See the code below for a stripped down version with notes.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

```
<?php 
/* 

    Let's asume that this is the search query in the address bar: 
    ?s=media&trend=&industry=&d=2012-05-17|2012-11-17
    (To iterate, it's saying search for keyword 'media' 
    posted between 17th May 2012 and 17th Novemer 2012)

    It gives 13 results and shows all on the same page. 
    I have set show 10 posts per page so it should be cutting off 
    at first 10. 

    PAGINATION: On line 56 If I change the code to 
    $wp_query->max_num_pages, the pagination works but then 
    repeats the same 10 posts. 

*/

// Setup pagination
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

// Sort trend taxonomy
$tr = $_GET['trend']; 
// Sort industry taxonomy
$ind = $_GET['industry']; 
// Set date var
$d = $_GET['d']; 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'trend' => $tr,
    'industry' => $ind
);  
// Date range function, if available                        
if( (isset($_GET['d'])) && ($_GET['d']!=='') ) {
    function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
        $date_range = $_GET['d'];
        $date_range = explode("|", $date_range);
        $that_date = $date_range[0]; 
        $this_date = $date_range[1];                                
        $where .= " AND post_date >= '".$that_date."' AND post_date <= '".$this_date."'";
        return $where;
    }
    // Add the filter 
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
}   

// setup the wp_query
$allsearch = new WP_Query($args); 

// Remove the date filter where clause
if( (isset($_GET['d'])) && ($_GET['d']!=='') ) {
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); 
}

while ( $allsearch->have_posts() ) : $allsearch->the_post(); 
    // Show the posts
endwhile;

// 
if ( $allsearch->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <div class="nextprev pagination">
    <div class="nav-previous"><span class="nextprev-arrow">&lsaquo;</span> <span class="nextprev-link-title">Older posts</span></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><span class="nextprev-arrow">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="nextprev-link-title">Newer posts</span></div>
    </div><!-- .nextprev -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: `showposts` and `posts_per_page` are conflicting. They [do the same thing](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters), and the former is deprecated, but you have them set differently. I don't know it that is the problem or not, but it is something I noticed.

Comment: Iv'e corrected this. And thanks but no joy. Any other ideas?

Comment: what does the URL look like for the second page? have you inspected the value of the paged query var to be sure it's what you expect? also `print_r($allsearch)` to see the SQL that WordPress is generating.

Comment: I checked all of that, but i managed to almost get it working by adding in `$limit = get_option('posts_per_page');` and `posts_per_page=".$limit."`. This works but now my `$wp_query->post_count` shows '10' on every page, even if 13 results are found. Almost there!!

Comment: `$wp_query->post_count` is referring to a different query. part of the issue is that you're using pagination parameters from the main query, but then creating an entirely new query. try using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to manipulate the query instead, it doesn't waste a query and will make these pagination issues go away.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Sorry still learning the ins and outs of wp_query.

Comment: Always +1 for `pre_get_posts`

Comment: `wp_reset_query` is not intended for `WP_Query` ( it cleans up `query_posts`, which you're not using here), use `wp_reset_postdata` instead ( you only need to call it if you call the_post too, so put it inside the `if ($query->have_posts())` not after it)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with a new Wp Query, as in your example, changing your $allsearch name for the query variable to $wp_query should do the trick. 
Looks like the pagination functions are expecting that variable name for the query... So, try that...

Comment: Please use formatting for code.